# Convert to Json and call page method

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have been trying to get this working for too long and thought I might ask for help here. I am trying to pass a javascript object to server side and then back to client side. Kind of like, on every postback I want to update the value of the object code behind or client side depending upon certain conditions. I can use hiddenfield here but I am trying to learn ajax so. 
I have declared a global variable client side called sortList which stores the info about what task is stored in what slot. So its like:

```
var sortList = {};
sortList[tid] = sid;
```

Next I wrote a web method:

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string storeList(DragList dict)
    {
        DragList dl = dict;
        int i = 0;
        return "success";
    }
public class DragList
    {
        public string taskName { get; set; }
        public string slotName { get; set; }


    }
```

and on the client side I am calling it using:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(sortList));
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Jobs.aspx/storeList",
            data: JSON.stringify({dict: sortList}),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(msg) {
                }});
        }
```

My problem is in the webmethod, the DragList object dict is always null, though in the request, dict is a json object with value in it. 
[image]

I have been stuck too long now on this and almost planning to move to hidden field to get the task done. But would really appreciate if some one could point me in the right direction.

Changes I made after:
I am using tid as a key to find sid in the object array, so if I break it into parts, I will lose the key value pairing. Instead, I created a new string in a proper JSON format:

```
jsonStr = "{";
            var w = 0;
            for (var key in sortList) {
                var obj = sortList[key];
                jsonStr += '"key":{"taskName":"' + key + '", "slotName":"' + obj + '"},';
                w++;
            }
            jsonStr = jsonStr.substring(0, jsonStr.length - 1);
            jsonStr += '}';
            console.log(jsonStr);


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Jobs.aspx/storeList",
            data: {dict: jsonStr},
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(msg) {
                }});
        }
```

But now, I get the following error: 
[image]

[image: Here is my post]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Json is wrong:

You are sending it as

```
{"taskName:mainContent_ptask5":"alotName:mainContent_palot0"}
```

Instead of

```
{"taskName":"mainContent_ptask5", "alotName":"mainContent_palot0"}
```

Former considers the property name as `taskName:mainContent_ptask5` so it cannot deserilaize to your argument name `taskName` or `slotName`

The culprit must be:

```
var sortList = {};
sortList[tid] = sid; // here i guess tid is "taskName:mainContent_ptask5" and sid is "alotName:mainContent_palot0"
```

Instead try something like this:

```
var tidParts = tid.split(':');
var sidParts = sid.split(':');
var sortList = { 
};
sortList[tidParts[0]] = tidParts[1];
sortList[sidParts[0]] = sidParts[1];
```

Comment: I cannot break it into parts as then I will lose my key value pairing of tasks to slots. Instead, I fixed my json string, but then I get an error. Please see the edit in the original post.

Comment: @Ratan yes right i dont know whats in there so made a guess but my point was clear...

Comment: @Ratan can you paste your concatenated JSON string. SOmthing probably wrong there. Try using object notation instead of concatenation. Also if it is string then try `{dict: JSON.parse(jsonStr)}`

Comment: The JSON string: {"key":{"taskName":"MainContent_ptask0", "slotName":"MainContent_pslot0"},"key":{"taskName":"MainContent_ptask1", "slotName":"MainContent_pslot1"}}

Comment: Yes your JSON is getting double encoded due to string concatination try this:-  `JSON.stringify({dict: JSON.parse(jsonStr)})`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31971/discussion-between-ratan-and-psl)